# Android : how to use custom views including QuickContactBadge or CompoundButton for Status Bar Notifications in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to figure out how to put compound buttons or QuickContactBadge(QCB) to status bar notifications. I am using remote Views to pass my custom layout and it works fine for ImageView, textViews etc but I get exceptions when I try to add compound buttons (ex. switch) or try to use Quick Contact Badge or my custom view. 
this is how the xml looks like

```
<QuickContactBadge 
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_small_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_small_size"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_generic_user_square_small"/>
```

this is how I am trying to post the notification

```
Intent notificationIntent;
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        builder.setTicker("Notification Alert");

        // This is where actual notification is constructed 
        notificationIntent = new Intent (this, MyActivity.class);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
        builder.setContent(contentView);

        mNotificationManager.notify(notification_alert_id, builder.getNotification());
```

And this is the exception I get when I try to run this

```
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212): couldn't inflate view for notification
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.QuickContactBadge
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:823)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:729)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:1570)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.tablet.TabletStatusBar.inflateViews(TabletStatusBar.java:1779)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.tablet.TabletStatusBar.addNotificationViews(TabletStatusBar.java:1587)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.tablet.TabletStatusBar.addNotification(TabletStatusBar.java:790)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:231)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.QuickContactBadge
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:618)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
02-14 20:07:40.014 E/TabletStatusBar( 1212):    ... 21 more
```

Is there any way I can get QCB or my custom view in notification when using remote views ? Will appreciate any help.

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure out how to put compound buttons or QuickContactBadge(QCB) to status bar notifications.

You can't. Those widgets are not available for `RemoteViews` on any current version of Android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way to send custom notification without using Remote Views ?? or Is there any other way I can use these widgets for Notifications ?